# dynamically change header text by controller or current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have some header text in a rails 3.2.13 app I want to dynamically change the text based on the current page or controller. Here is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
    <% if current_user.present? %>
    <div class="container push_down push_left">
  <div class="site-samples">
     <div class="span2 push_nav">
          <h3>Dashboard</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="span2 push_nav">
          <dl class="palette palette-info"><center><%= link_to 'Videos',    dashboard_videos_path, :class => 'palette'%></center></dl>
    </div>

    <div class="span2 push_nav">
      <dl class="palette palette-bright-dark"><center><%= link_to 'Statistics',   dashboard_statistics_path, :class => 'palette' %></center></dl>
    </div>

    <div class="span2 push_nav">
      <dl class="palette palette-alizarin"><center><%= link_to 'Account',   edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'palette' %></center></dl>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: pass some parameter on 'dashboard_videos_path', dashboard_videos_path(:head => "someHeaderText").'dashboard_statistics_path'.... like  this dashboard_statistics_path(:head => "someHeaderText") and passed it to veiws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `url_for` with the option you required for your app.

Like this one -

> :only_path - If true, returns the relative URL (omitting the protocol,
>   host name, and port) (true by default unless :host is specified).

Reference - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for